# Has anybody built an el7 RPM for Apache 2.2?

Tags: centos7, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, apache2.2

We are moving to centos 7 but have components that depend on Apache 2.2.  Most of the online stuff I've seen for people needing Apache 2.2 say "stick with centos 6" but that is not an option.

Has anybody here created an Apache 2.2 rpm for centos 7?  Or at least give me some pointers?  I have downloaded the Apache 2.2 source tarball and it compiles on c7 ... but how would I package it up?

Comment: Good luck. I dealt with building Apache RPMs years ago and it was a giant convoluted spaghetti mess of dependencies because it uses so many tiny pieces of different projects. I don't remember any of the details, sorry. But I'll warn you it is definitely non-trivial, if possible.

Comment: Thanks.   Here's hoping someone else has something better ;-)